# All methods to add JavaScript to SharePoint 2010 - Online

Tags: javascript

I am working on documentation of all methods of adding JavaScript to a page

I have some blanks I can not test easily, does anyone know the answers?

- When Office365 is configured to NOT allow Custom Scripts
- Computed columns in the New Document Library experience

[image]

Comment: As soon as you finish this, Office 365 will push an update that will make it obsolete. Also, not all tenants always have the same set of features so things may work in some tenants but not in others.

Comment: I follow PnP Yammer groups; I also have a script monitoring the build changes in multiple O365 Tenants. What set of features/scenarios am I missing?

Comment: I don't know.  O365 is constantly changing, so trying to document it seems not worth the effort. The new doc lib experience, for example, is so new you can almost guarantee there will soon be sweeping changes to it. Also, the SharePoint Framework scheduled for Q4 will undoubtedly change the front-end game.

Comment: Then I dare to say this overview is pretty complete (as I am the asshole on Yammer who is Microsoft tail with all this front-end stuff :-)